# Why does Linux need DRM (Digital rights management) for audio and video?

Tags: linux, browser

Hope this is the right place for this question:

Linux requires DRM (digital rights management) to be enabled in firefox to support popular streaming services. Why is that? Is it to with the fact that most Linux OS are open source?

N.B. From wikipedia - Digital rights management (DRM) tools or technological protection measures are a set of access control technologies for restricting the use of proprietary hardware and copyrighted works.

Comment: Just checking that you are certain that DRM is not actually "[Direct Rendering Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager)"?

Comment: `Linux requires DRM to be enabled in the default browser to support popular streaming services` - where does it say that? Where are you getting this from? For context can you [edit] and provide the link/source.

Comment: Popular streaming service that require DRM (most of them) do require it to be enabled in ANY OS. Why would it be different in Linux?

Comment: What is the "default browser"? DRM is required by the streaming services, not by GNU/Linux nor even browsers. GNU/Linux users are usually more aware of the harmful nature of Digital Restrictions Management and proprietary software, so in some distributions the distinction is clearly made, and to install DRM you have to make an extra step (install additional packages, run installation scripts...).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Your question isn't really related to Linux. you have to enable DRM management in Firefox on Windows as well. DRM are use to limit piracy in web streaming in legal services, this uses proprietary code that isn't enable by default, that's all.

Comment: Linux doesn't require it, those "popular streaming services" require it. It's just that in windows you don't have a choice to not enable it in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Just checking, you probably meant [Direct rendering manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager), am I right? I have never heard of digital rights management in Linux.

Comment: There exists DRM (Digital Restrictions Management) software on GNU/Linux. Example: https://sourceforge.net/software/digital-rights-management/linux/ For example, Firefox includes a setting that enables Digital Restrictions Management, which enables Netflix to be watched https://itsfoss.com/netflix-firefox-linux/ [Why I use the term "Restrictions"](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/words-to-avoid.html#DigitalRightsManagement),

Comment: Oh, these are not parts of Linux, they seem like they are software that enables you to use websites and media that requires them to prevent illegally copying movies, etc. They are not a part of GNU/Linux, just a third party software.

Comment: It is software which runs under GNU/Linux. It is not maintained by the GNU Project, nor it is part of Linux (kernel), but it is DRM on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I just answered the question. It is a third party software required by third party software to manage digital rights. I think the DRM might be included in Windows and MacOS by default. Windows has something called PlayReady.

Comment: You didn't answer the OP's question, you asked a different question, seeking clarification from the OP and made an off-topic remark about "not hearing of digital rights management in Linux", to which I gave a counter example.

Comment: "they seem like they are software that enables you to use websites and media that requires them to prevent illegally copying movies, etc." I think this pretty much answers the question.